# PyWin32 PostMessage or SendMessage won't send keystrokes without window focus on BlueStacks

Tags: python, pywin32, sendmessage, postmessage, hwnd

I can get my code to work if the window is in focus. However, if I test this on Notepad or other programs it works just fine. I use the same method to simulate mouse clicks without focus. It just doesn't want to send keystrokes without window focus.

I have tried using both SendMessage and PostMessage and my HWND is the child window that accepts the message (I also tried going down the tree and using more children HWNDs)

Does anyone have a workaround? I'm open to using different libraries I just don't want to focus the window.

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, win32ui 
import time

def send_input_hax(msg,pycwnd):
    for c in msg:
        if c == "\n":
            pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
            pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
        else:
            pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(c), 0)

def click(x,y,pycwnd):
    lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x,y)
    pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
    pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam);

def get_whndl():
    whndl = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, 'BlueStacks')
    return whndl

def make_pycwnd(hwnd):       
    PyCWnd = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(hwnd)
    return PyCWnd

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'BlueStacks')
whndl = get_whndl()

def callback(hwnd, hwnds):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
        hwnds[win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)] = hwnd
    return True

hwnds = {}
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(whndl, callback, hwnds)
whndl = hwnds['plrNativeInputWindowClass']
pycwnd = make_pycwnd(whndl)

time.sleep(5)
send_input_hax('red')
```

Comment: You're supposed to use SendInput to synthesize keyboard input. You might also have to use SetFocus to set the focus to a window that accepts the input

Comment: Yes, I have tried using SetFocus to get it running temporarily,  and it works. However, if I am typing or clicking while it is running it will send other keystrokes to the program. The goal is to get it running while other tasks can be done on the computer.

Comment: That's sadly not how Windows works. There can only be a single application/window that has keyboard focus. At least nominally. maybe there are some weird tricks you could try, but I'm general this isn't possible. You could see about running the program in a separate login session though.